# How to format the price on the backend

Tags: magento2, php, price, array, format

I have a variable `$ customerProductPrices` that contains data like this.
[image]

How to format data (price, special_price, price_value, special_price_value) in a variable
That I would get not just a number, but a formatted number with currency.
Tentatively, the variable will contain not only 0 arrays, but more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you haven't mentioned where the array variable **`$_customerProductPrices`** is from, whether its from a Block or from a ViewModel or in a template (.phtml file). As well as its also not mentioned how do you get this , whether through a repository method or from a collection or any other approach

**Quick but Ugly**

lets assume that its in a template file

in this case, loop through your array and get the variable formatted through this simple helper method

```
$priceFormatted = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format($_customerProductPrices[$keyindex]['price'], 2), true, false);
```

**Better Approach**

Inside your class where you get this variable, inject the interface **`Magento/Framework/Pricing/PriceCurrencyInterface`** and make use of the methods `format` or `convertAndFormat`

```
public function format(
        $amount,
        $includeContainer = true,
        $precision = self::DEFAULT_PRECISION,
        $scope = null,
        $currency = null
    );


    public function convertAndFormat(
        $amount,
        $includeContainer = true,
        $precision = self::DEFAULT_PRECISION,
        $scope = null,
        $currency = null
    );
```

These are the methods implemented by  `**Magento\Directory\Model\PriceCurrency**`

you can also inject this class in your module class (Block / ViewModel) and make use of the **format** and **convert** methods in that concrete class

[check the source here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.3/app/code/Magento/Directory/Model/PriceCurrency.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using what the class`vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/PriceCurrency.php` has to offer with its `format()` method. Check how this is used inside `vendor/magento/module-customer-balance/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Create/Payment.php` class.

Comment: What is the difference between convertAndFormat & format ?